# Is signal level same as rssi ? They are both in dbm and they change when I move around

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, signals, physics

I am working on a project that uses rssi values of surrounding wifis to get a position of the device but the thing is that the language i.e flutter doesn't have a package regarding rssi but has a package that returns signal level in dbm .

Answer (score 0):

RSSi (dBm) = (0.474 * LRES) – 112.  ref https://support.dialog-semiconductor.com/convert-rssi-dbm